# How do I open a Photo attached to a text Message?

Tags: sms, mms

I have just bought a Samsung Galaxy S and have been sent a Text message with a photo but cannot find out how to open the photo to view when I touch the message thread it just comes up with message details help please still trying to get used to the phone and cannot find in manual!!!!

Comment: Heather, you'll get better responses if you give this question a real title. I think you mean to ask "How do I open a photo attached to a text message?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

1. On the messaging app, (without opening any thread), tap on the menu key and go to Settings.

   1. Scroll down to Multimedia message (MMS) Settings section and turn off "Auto-retrieve"
   2. Next time you view the message, the message will display a download button.
   3. Make sure your mobile data is on, and tap on the button. The image will be retrieved and displayed inline on Galaxy S.

Comment: *Comment by Darren:* Thank you, worked 100% for me, the key was to turn on mobile data and not just wifi.